# Simple Injector - Inject specific implementation of interface to specific controller

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, umbraco, simple-injector

I have two search services that implement the same interface. One of them is used to search only within a small set of internal Umbraco content, the other searches through both Umbraco and external content and uses other than default search engine. I'd like to keep both of them, as each of them performs well, for the set of data it uses.

Is it possible in Simple Injector to specify, when to inject which service? I'd like to register the first one for most of the controllers, basically as a default implementation. Then, I need to register the second one only for two specific controllers.

While browsing I've found a solution to this issue, but it's in Ninject:

```
Bind<ITeamRespository>().To<SoccerRepository>().WhenInjectedInto(typeof(SoccerController));
```

Is the same thing doable with Simple Injector?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Simple Injector equivalent is:

```
container.RegisterConditional<ITeamRespository, SoccerRepository>(
    c => c.Consumer.ImplementationType == typeof(SoccerController));

container.RegisterConditional<ITeamRespository, FallbackRepository>(c => !c.Handled);
```

More information can be found in the [documentation](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced.html#context-based-injection).

Comment: First of all, thanks for the answer. I was trying to get the RegisterConditional working, as I felt this might be the answer. However, after using it when I started the application I got a YSOD, saying that I couldn't use RegisterConditional, because AllowOverridingRegistrations flag was set to true. I need to be able to override registrations, to use RegisterConfigurations. What I did, was to RegisterConditional the interface and after that set the AllowOverridingRegistrations to true. This works, but I'm just unsure if there will be some consequences of coding it like that.

Comment: @Slowacki: I hardly ever override registrations myself, and find it much safer to have the bootstrapper for the business layer to bootstrap everything that doesn't need to be replaced by the end application and force the end application to explicitly 'fill the holes'.

Comment: @Slowacki: Simple Injector is very strict in his conditional registrations. For instance, if it finds two applicable conditional registrations when resolving a service, it will throw an exception. Simple Injector hardly ever fails silently. But as you already noticed, Simple Injector does not allow overriding conditional registrations, because that would lead to ambiguity (and thus meant Simple Injector would failing silently, which is something we tend to prevent).

Comment: Yes, unfortunately noticed that when I tried to resolve a service manually in a static class: ISearchService searchService = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ISearchService>() was failing. In the end, I've decided to split the search interface into 2 separate ones, IdResolver and Search, which actually makes more sense in terms of their responsibilities and with 2 separate registrations it works just fine. Thanks for all the information and help!

Comment: @Slowacki: Two things. 1. The fact that `GetService<ISearchService>()` fails means that you are not calling `container.Verify()` which really is advisable. 2. My experience is that conditional registrations are often an indication of a sub optimal design, so it's great to hear that this process brought you to a better design. Good work!